# ¿Por que? No se guardar mis datos en mis tablas PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

**Hola soy nuevo en este ámbito de PHP, y tengo un problema se los explico, tengo dos tablas una de *compania* y otra de *producto* lo que sucede es que cuando le doy guardar, los datos no se guarda valga la redundancia no entiendo por que sera. les dejo el codigo aqui**

```
<?php
include 'ConexionBD/conexionbd.php';
include 'session.php';


if (isset($_POST['btn_compania'])) {
$id_usuario = $login_id;
$id_categoria = trim($_POST['id_categoria']);
$c_compania = trim($_POST['c_compania']);
print_r($query_sql = "INSERT INTO tb_compania(id_usuario, id_categoria, 
c_compania) VALUES ('$id_usuario','$id_categoria','$c_compania')");

print_r($variable = $_REQUEST['field_name']);

foreach ($variable as $value) {
    $id_compania = 1;
    $p_producto = $value;
    print_r($query_sql = "INSERT INTO tb_producto(id_compania, p_producto) VALUES ('$id_compania','$p_producto')");
}

 $respuesta = mysqli_multi_query($conn,$query_sql);
 if ($respuesta) {
     echo "Todo bien";
 }else{
     echo "todo mal";
 }
 mysqli_close($conn); }?>
```

Cuando le paso el print_r se daran cuenta que los datos si son capturados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para usar `mysqli_multi_query` las consultas deben estar separadas por `;` ([revisa los ejemplos de código del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php)). Intenta mostrar el mensaje de error para ver qué es lo que pasa, poniendo esta línea así: **`echo "todo mal: {mysqli_error($conn)}";`** y dinos qué muestra. Otra cosa, para estos casos evita poner capturas de pantalla, es mejor que pongas el texto directamente.

Comment: pues a final, solo me sirvió el {mysqli_error($conn)}

Comment: (https://we.tl/t-DgVXHiRsz6) aquí esta como lo arregle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega el operador `.=` en el `foreach`:

```
print_r($query_sql .= "INSERT INTO tb_producto(id_compania, p_producto) VALUES ('$id_compania','$p_producto')");
```